# How can I block Reddit.self posts?

Tags: reddit, safari

I've used [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) (RES) in Safari for some time now to filter out stuff I don't want to see, but I'd really like to block all self posts. I've tried going through the options, but nothing jumps out at me as a way to block them.

Is there a way to do it with RES? Or is there another extension for Safari that'll do it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this using [Reddit Enhancement Suite (RES)](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) in Chrome* by adding "self" as a "domain" filter. Go to https://www.reddit.com/#res:settings/filteReddit, add the keyword and press save on the top-right corner:

[image: domain filter option]

<sub>*Also works for Firefox, Safari, and Opera browsers</sub>

Comment: Please give some more info. This is using Reddit Enhancement Suite, and is not a core feature. I suggest giving some more information about this if you want it to be a suitable answer.

Comment: Thanks sable for adding some more information. I will make a quick edit to it and it looks good! I have removed my downvote and have upvoted this now! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe that RES has such a function nor have I stumbled upon such an extension/app. I would suggest making a feature request in RES's subreddit which the authors actively read and check up on.

[/r/Enhancement](http://www.reddit.com/r/Enhancement)

Comment: Should you remove this answer when hiding posts is possible as told in the other answer?