# How can I hide Reddit link posts?

Tags: reddit

I want to hide posts that are just submitted links, as I'm only interested in reading original content, not viewing images, videos, memes and spam blogs.

Hiding text posts ("self post") is possible with [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) (see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/52642/134950)).

How can I do something similar with posts that are links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filteReddit filter in settings ([direct link](https://www.reddit.com/#res:settings/filteReddit)). Under "custom filters", select "add a custom filter" > "add a condition" > "post type" > "post is a link post". Press "save options" on the top-right corner.

[image: options screenshot]

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Enhancement/comments/7fxi7w/is_there_a_link_submission_alternative_to_the/dqf1l1v/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the linked answer, if you can avoid self posts in Enhancement Suite by using domain `self`, you can avoid everything which is not `self` by using a regular expression `/^(?!(self)$)/i`

This tells RES to hide everything but self posts.

Comment: Using the filter hides *everything*. I've tried moving the filter to the top of the rules. I added the filter to "domains" in "filteReddit" just like in the linked answer: https://i.imgur.com/5LHWseW.png